# Is an analytic function determined by its values on a lattice?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we know the values of a complex analytic function $f$ at all $x+iy$, for $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Can we uniquely determine $f$?

More generally, are there examples of nowhere-dense sets $E$ s.t. $f\mid_E$ determines $f$?

Comment: Equivalently: Are there nowhere-dense sets $E$ such that if $f$ vanishes on $E$ it vanishes on $\mathbb C$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No to your first question.  The [Weierstrass factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem) asserts that for any sequence $\{a_n\}$ of nonzero complex numbers with $|a_n| \to \infty$, there is a nontrivial analytic function $f$ whose zero set is precisely $\{a_n\}$.  Clearly we can enumerate all the nonzero points $a_n$ of the integer lattice in such a way that $|a_n| \to \infty$, so there is a nontrivial analytic $f$ vanishing at all those points.  Then the function $z f(z)$ is also not the zero function, but vanishes at all those points and 0 as well.

Yes to your second question.  [The zeros of a nontrivial analytic function must be isolated.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Zeroes_of_Analytic_Function_are_Isolated)  So take $E$ to be any nowhere dense set that has a limit point (for instance, the set $\{1/n : n = 1, 2, \dots\} \cup \{0\}$).  If $f,g$ are analytic functions which agree on $E$, then $f-g$ is an analytic function whose zero set has a limit point, hence $f-g=0$.

Comment: +1: So (correct me if I'm wrong), one might say that $f\mid_E$ fails to uniquely determine $f$ if and only if $E$ is a discrete set. Does that seem to be a fair summary?

Comment: @CameronBuie: No, careful.  The set $E = \{1/n : n = 1,2,\dots\}$ is discrete (every point is isolated), but it does uniquely determine $f$ (since it has a limit point, namely 0).  I think it holds iff $E$ is a *closed* discrete set, or equivalently, has no limit points.  You have to show that such $E$ is countable and can be enumerated as a sequence $\{a_n\}$ with $|a_n| \to \infty$, but I believe this follows by considering a sequence of balls $B(0,m)$; by compactness, each such ball contains only finitely many points of $E$.

Comment: Aha! Right you are.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Thanks.  I misstated the second question.  I really meant, are there sets with no accumulation points that can determine $f$.  I forgot that sets like $\{1/n\}$ count as nowhere-dense.

Comment: @TorsionSquid: Ok, then the answer is no, as explained in my previous comment.